# Twitter and Facebook login support in EE

Tags: members, accounts, comments, single-sign-on

What do you recommend for implementing EE member sign-on support using Facebook and Twitter accounts?

We are having a lot of trouble with our CAPTCHAs with EE comments and so we are considering dumping the captcha and just requiring an account to be able to comment. In order to make it a little more open though, we'd like to let people use their Twitter or Facebook log-in to sign-in. Someone has recommended [Social Login Pro](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/social-login-pro), but are there other add-ons that are recommended or are we better off implementing our own solution using the Twitter and Facebook APIs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about [Disqus](http://disqus.com)? Personally, I prefer sites that use Disqus for commenting than Facebook comments. Of course, that's not the entirety of your question. In terms of an easy-to-use sign-on. [Social Login Pro](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/social-login-pro) seems to be the way to go, if you want people to be able to choose, which account they want to sign-in for.

I like that it allows Google and Twitter, but haven't used it on a client project yet. I have used Solspace's [Facebook Connect](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/facebook_connect/) and thought that was very good, but it's all about Facebook (which worked for the project I used it on). I have it queued up for a new project, so I'm interested in seeing what's new in version 2.x of the add-on.

Generally speaking though, if you want Social Media login, I think Social Login Pro is probably the way to go. But I'd still consider switching to Disqus for comments.

Comment: We have thought about moving to Disqus, but jump back and forth on that. This would really about being able to log into the site with an external account Facebook or Twitter, but I think we still would like that process to set up an EE user account. I need to look deeper at Social Pro to see if that is possible.

Answer (score 2):

If Spam through your current comment forms is the issue then there is a great add-on to stop spam in EE called **Snaptcha**. We were getting a lot of Spam on a site we had built and this STOPPED the spam immeadiately. I can't recomend it enough. Super simple to implement.

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/snaptcha

---

We have recently used Disqus on another site we just launched to enable people to comment using their social login.

Another great add-on is **CX Disqus Comments** which enables two way comment sync and lets you export your existing EE comments to Disqus, and automatically sync new Discus comments back to the ExpressionEngine database for SEO and backup purposes.

This sounds like it could be perfect for you.

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cx-disqus-comments